# Sorting large number of strings(10^8) of large sizes(10^8) in c++

Tags: string, sorting

Can anybody tell me how to sort large number strings of large sizes in c++. I m not able to build any logic. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you sort a small number of short strings? What alægorithm did you use? What happened when you tried to use the same algorithm on a large number of large strings?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a case where sorting pointers to strings would work well.  You don't specify a lot of the information which would help provide a good solution.  If the strings are on disk, the solution may be different than if the strings are in memory.  When and if you move the strings may depend on where they are located, and what the access requirements are.

Merge sort algorithms tend to work well with large sets.  With large key sizes, sorting a prefix of the key gets you sets which are easier/faster to sort.  It's much easier to sort all the keys starting with `a` than all the keys.  If you are working with sets with the same prefix, you can skip the prefix and sort on the next part of the key.  You are done when all of the prefix sets are of size 1.

Comment: Actually I am trying to calculate BWT (burrows-wheeler transform) but it requires a matrix of 10^8 X 10^8 size that i cannot build in c++.

Comment: Memory requirements would likely force you to disk.  This will significantly slow your sorting. Sorting prefixes may speed it up as you won't need to read the whole entry on each pass.